# How to select records that have multiple values in a related table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following three tables for tagging content where each content can have one-to-many tags. For example, a content record could have a tag of California and Variable.

Table w/ the content

```
Content
-ContentID
-ContentName
```

Table w/ the tags

```
Tag
-TagID
-TagName
```

Table that links the content and the tags

```
ContentTag
-ContentID
-TagID
```

With the following SELECT statement I want to get records with TagID of both 21 and 54 however no rows are returned.

```
SELECT * FROM ContentTag
INNER JOIN Content On ContentTag.ContentID=Content.ContentID
INNER JOIN Tag ON ContentTag.TagID=Tag.TagID
Where (Tag.TagID=21 And Tag.TagID=54)
```

How do I create a SQL SELECT statement to retrieve content that has one-to-many tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to approach this question using aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
SELECT c.ContentId, c.ContentName
FROM ContentTag ct INNER JOIN
     Content c
     On ct.ContentID = c.ContentID 
WHERE ct.TagID IN (21, 54)
GROUP BY c.ContentId, c.ContentName
HAVING COUNT(Distinct ct.TagId) = 2;
```

Some notes:

- You don't need the `join` to the tags table.  You are using the id and which is in `ContentTag`.
- You don't need `*`.  I presume you are looking content that has the two tags.
- The `WHERE` clause limits the tags to the two tags in question.
- The `HAVING` clause makes sure both are there.

Comment: Gordon, In where condition, you have used t.TagID but alias 't' is of which table in the SELECT query.

Comment: @PareshJ . . . That alias should be `ct` not `t`.

Comment: How to do it if i have a list of TagIds which can be more than two tag?

Comment: @Harry.Naeem . . . You would add them to the `IN` list and increment the `2`.